# Find paths of binomial tree in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, data-structures, tree

Suppose I have a matrix where reverse (recombining) lower triangular is a binomial tree with initial node has value 4 (lower left), branching out to 3 & 5, with 3 branching to 2 & 4, and 5 branching to 4 & 6, and so on.

```
m = ((0, 0, 6),
     (0, 5, 4),
     (4, 3, 2))
```

This is visual representation:
[image]

How can I find all unique paths in this tree as tuples?
Naturally, there will be $2^n$ paths for a tree with $n$ steps (that is $n+1$ terminal nodes).

```
[(4,3,2), (4,3,4), (4,5,4), (4,5,6)]
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:
-make some traversal of the tree for example, BFS or DFS.
The simplest way is recursive

```
procedure Walk(node, route)
  if node = nil then //leaf node is reached
     output(route)
  else   
    Walk(node.left, route + node.name)
    Walk(node.right, route + node.name)

Walk(root, empty)
```

- map numbers in range 0..2<sup>n</sup>-1 with possible routes:
if i-th bit (from left) of number is 1, at i-th level use right branch, else use left branch. For example, (4,5,4) corresponds to number 2 = binary 10